# Elasticsearch: bulk index json with _id provided

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have a big file which has a JSON object on each line. A single line would look similar to this:

```
{"_id":0, "foreign_key":-1, "text":"foobar"}
```

I am very well aware that I could just rename `_id` to, for example, `primary_key` and I wouldn't encounter the problem, but still I'd like to know if I can use the ID I calculated for my object in ES' `_id` field.

The following sample code fails, it is disallowed to specifiy the meta field `_id` in the JSON object itself.

Apart from the renaming solution in the previous paragraph I could also specify the `_id` manually in the `IndexRequestBuilder`. But my file contains more than half a million lines and I am not willing to give up performance when parsing the JSON to extract the ID from it.

```
private void indexAll() {
    TransportClient client + ... // setup omitted for brevity
    BulkRequestBuilder bulkRequest = client.prepareBulk();

    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.list(myFile)) {
        stream.forEach(l -> addRequest(bulkRequest, client, l));
    }

    BulkResponse bulkResponse = bulkRequest.get();
    if (bulkResponse.hasFailures()) {
        // error handling
    }
}

private void addRequest(BulkRequest bulk, TransportClient client, String line) {
    IndexRequestBuilder req = client.prepareIndex("myIndex", "_doc"):
    req.setSource(line, XContentType.JSON);
    bulk.add(req);
}
```

So is there a way to index the JSON objects as given and use their `_id`?

Comment: you can use the `setId` method on your `IndexRequestBuilder`

Comment: @IanGabes correct, but then I would need to modifiy the line. Parse the id field, removing it from the json object, ... and that for all half a million lines. I'm not happy with the performance impact.